# How to print several pictures in x86 one after another?

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

I am working on a game and I have 3 puctures that need to be displayed one after another : the one when you open the game, instructions and background.
The code I am using seems to work only when I have one image to display(or used to)
the code:

```
filename db 'cover.bmp' , 0
sfilename db 'in.bmp' , 0
tfilename db 'piano.bmp', 0
filehandle dw ? ; the saved place
ErrorMsg db 'Error', 13, 10 ,'$' 
; --------------------------
CODESEG
proc OpenFile
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax dx
; Open file
    mov ah, 3Dh
    xor al, al
    mov dx, [bp+4] ;offset filename 
    int 21h
    jc openerror
        mov [filehandle], ax
        ret
    openerror :
    mov dx, offset ErrorMsg
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    pop dx ax bp
ret
endp OpenFile

start :
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
; Graphic mode
mov ax, 13h
int 10h
; Process BMP file
push offset filename
call OpenFile
call ReadHeader
call ReadPalette
call CopyPal
call CopyBitmap
; Wait for key press
mov ah,1
int 21h
; Back to text mode
mov ah, 0
mov al, 2
int 10h
```

the procs ReadHeader , ReadPalette, copyPal, copyBitmap are procs that I got from the teacher, I never changed them and they don't need the filename. When I run the code, I get the error message instantly. All the files are stored in my computer.

Comment: This code only opens 1 file.  Can we see the code you use when you attempt to open the second one?

Comment: Also, where did you get that code for OpenFile?  It seems to leave the stack messed up if it successfully opens the file.

Comment: It's normal for functions to return in AX (maybe with an error status in CF).  It's really weird for a function to store the value you want into static storage (named global variable).

Comment: @davidWohlfred to use other picturei repeat the code under the comment "process bmp file" but push offset of the second picture. 
I got the code from my teacher, he said that I should use it and never explained.